# How to run `gsettings set` in chroot?

Tags: chroot, gsettings

I ran the following command in chroot environment without X:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-reader-enabled true`

I get the following error message:

```
(process:8290): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=09be9504960407430fb3a253000052a5 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: No protocol specified\nNo protocol specified\nAutolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Is X a must for changing gsettings? Is there another way to change the setting? (My purpose is to make a LiveCD iso with screen reader enabled by default)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's [possible](http://php.mandelson.org/wp2/?p=565) to run `gsettings` without X11 using `dbus-launch --exit-with-session`:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-reader-enabled true
```

Comment: “No protocol specified” when this is tested in a chroot environment (namely Gentoo Catalyst).